# Clarification needed on Concept of a listener anonymous class in java

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to java. What is the purpose of a listener anonymous inner class design? I heard that anonymous classes are used as listeners in java. And that no one really creates inner classes or even static inner classes. I'm not sure what that means. could some one explain these concepts a bit? Especially this listener design and how its created via an anonymous class.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See some of the Related answers at right, and/or see a tutorial on whatever you're trying to set up a listener on (which will almost certainly have examples). Anonymous classes are a convenient shorthand, nothing more. And yes, inner classes *are* used when appropriate; learning what is and isn't appropriate is something that comes with experience and reading examples.

Comment: Could you site your sources regarding `"no one really creates inner classes or even static inner classes"`? Sorry, but this statement seems blatantly false.

Comment: That's what I've heard. The only time one needs inner classes is for scoping rules. I was under the impression that static inner are used to restrict instantiation some how, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymous listener would usually look something like this:

```
myControl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Handle event
    }
});
```

Using an inner class to accomplish the same goal would usually look something like this:

```
public void init()
{
    myControl.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
}

private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Handle event
    }
}
```

Now consider what the two would look like in the scope of a much larger program. The anonymous listener is still right there at the spot where you're adding it. The inner class may be somewhere else in the source file entirely. With a good IDE, that difference can be minimized (such as a members browser), but is there really a need for an entirely new class for something you're going to use *once?*

Of course, depending on the exact needs of your application, a separate class might in fact be a better choice. If, for example, you have many listeners that differ only a little bit, you could construct something along these lines:

```
public void init()
{
    myControl1.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("foo"));
    myControl2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("bar"));
    myControl3.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("baz"));
}

private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    private String word;

    public MyActionListener(String word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Handle event
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

As far as static classes go: in Java, an inner class can be marked `static`, and all this does is prevent it from having a reference to the instance of the enclosing class. (For example, `MyProgram.MyStaticClass` would not be able to access any members of `MyProgram` which weren't static, unless it creates a *new* instance of `MyProgram`.) This may help with separation-of-concerns, but doesn't change very much when it comes to listeners.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the static inner classes? I thought static prevents for example having an outer class called "Wallet.java" being able to instantiate many static inner "CreditCard" classes. I'm not sure why we would use static inner classes actually.

Comment: @TazMan, No, static classes in Java are not (necessarily) singleton. Only inner classes can be static in Java, and all it does is prevent them having a reference to the enclosing object. If you have an instance of `MyClass` called `a`, then nothing in `a.MyStaticClass` references `a` unless you, for example, pass `a` as a parameter to one of `a.MyStaticClass`'s methods. In other languages (such as C#), static classes work differently.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. About the code example you provided, I don't know anything about controls in java, and GUI in general. Is that the only time listeners are used? Could you provide a more general "hello world" type example to clarify my doubts? When I see the word control and action listener, I get completely confused and forced to think about GUI.. Thank you.

Comment: @TazMan, GUI is probably the most common use for it, but [Event Driven Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) is not limited to only GUI. The linked wikipedia article should help some of your confusion! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not true, that no one creates named classes to handle events. Yet most of the time event handlers actually are anonymous classes. The reason for that is that anonymous classes offer less code and less files to maintain and it's easier to read a code when you don't have to jump between many small files. Anonymous classes shouldn't be too long (i.e. no more than ~20 lines of code), if they are longer, they should be converted to named classes. Anonymous classes are common in java version less than 8. In java 8 there are Lambda expressions, which are similar to anonymous classes, but they are more compact.

Comment: Named classes don't *have* to be in separate files; I sometimes used a named inner class or named static nested class as a listener.  Since those are nested inside another class, they're not separate files.  I usually use anonymous classes for this purpose, but at times I've found it necessary to give them names.

Comment: That's true, named classes doesn't have to be in a separate files.

Answer (score 0):

In languages with support for first class functions listeners can be implemented like this:

```
def myFunction() { //code }

button.onClick(myFunction)
```

for simplicity some languages has the capability to define anonymous functions (aka lambdas):

```
button.onClick({ // code})
```

Are called "anonymous" because don't need a name to reference it, are used in place.

Java don't has first class functions, instead the listener pattern is implemented with a class that implement some interface:

```
class myListener implements ButtonListener {
   public void listen(...);
}

button.onClick(myListener)
```

Analogous to the anonymous functions, for simplicity, java has the concept of anonymous classes, you can do:

```
button.onClick(new ButtonListener { 
   public void listen(..) { //code }
});
```

Note: this are simple "ilustrative" examples with an invented on the fly api :P

In java 8 first class functions (closures) are introduced, a huge and very good addition to java IMMO.

Inner classes: sometimes is good that one class is defined within the scope of another class, not the most useful java property IMMO, i use occasionally but can live without it in other languages.